# How to get cst_key from Avectra netforum?

Tags: php, authentication, avectra

I have username/password to access xweb functions. With Authenticate function, im able to get auth token by SOAP request. Auth token is the cst_key??

For reference, im using this tutorial [Member Management](http://jasonleveille.com/blog/2008/04/avectra-member-management-api/)

After that which function, i need to use to get a specific member details.
Please help

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rxbass, do you have access to the technical documentation? Work with your client or Avectra to get access as the API methods are all documented.

To answer your specific question, the Authenticate method returns a Token that is just a randomly generated key and is used to authenticate your API user's identify. It has nothing to do with customers in netFORUM. You must pass this token's value in the SOAP header to subsequent method calls. That token is *not* a cst_key.

TO get more information about a particular member, you'll need that member's cst_key somehow. We might need more information to provide a helpful answer.

More info:
rxbass, in your subsequent requests, are you providing the **Token** you received from **Authenticate** in the SOAP header?

As a simple test to make sure your account is set up properly, try running a simple method like [GetVersion](http://wiki.avectra.com/GetVersion). See code sample below; replace the "999999999" string with the Token that was returned by Authenticate. If that method isn't working for you, then there are underlying setup issues and you should address them through your support channels.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.avectra.com/2005/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns:AuthorizationToken>
            <ns:Token>999999999999999999999999999999999</ns:Token>
        </ns:AuthorizationToken>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:GetVersion/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: i have access to it. But except Authentication method, i'm receiving request timed out error for rest of the methods.

Comment: rxbass, I expanded my original answer to try to help. I suspect something is off with the setup of your user or the site. You shouldn't be getting timeouts from all the other methods. You might need to address this through your customer support channels.

Answer (score 1):

The authentication token is not the cst_key. The authentication token is passed as a parameter to each of the other methods.

Typically, you will use the WebLogin (turns credentials they typed into a user auth token, not to be confused with the web service authentication token above) method followed by the WebValidate (turns a user auth token into a cstkey) method to get a cstKey, and then use that cstKey to call GetIndividualInformation.